# How to export content type with scheduler's settings using features

Tags: nodes, features

In my dev environnement, I've installed [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module for exporting the content types of my site. I've also installed [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to schedule for publishing my contents.
On the admin page of my content type, I enabled scheduled publishing for my content type. Then I created the features of the content type. However after importing of features to the prod, I've found that the scheduler's settings to content type were not imported.

Does anybody know why? Is there any module supporting to resolve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to exporting "Content types", "Field bases" and "Field instances" you should also export all variables named "scheduler_*_[name of the content type]".

To be able to export variables [Strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module should be installed.
Then on "Create Feature" page you will see section as on this screenshot.

[image]

BTW, lot of modules that extend content types save their configuration the same way, so you need include such variables in the the content type feature.